# чем использовать атомарные операции лучше чем блокировать мьютексами?

Tags: linux, многопоточность, атомарность

здравствуйте, часто слышу что нужно писать так:

```
atomic int i = 0;
multithreaded_func() {
    i++;
}
поток 1(multithreaded_func());
поток 2(multithreaded_func());
```

вместо:

```
mutex m;
int i =0;
multithreaded_func() {
    m.lock();
    i++;
    m.unlock();
}
поток 1(multithreaded_func());
поток 2(multithreaded_func());
```

из-за того, что первый вариант выполняется быстрее... объясните, почему первый вариант выполняется быстрее, если те же самые мьютексы могут быть реализованы с помощью, опять же, атомарных операций? интересует linux x86/x86_64

допустим этот код:

```
std::atomic<int> i = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);
int j = 0;

std::mutex m;
int main() {
    i++;
    m.lock();
    j++;
    m.unlock();
}

для i++:
    lock addl       $1, i(%rip)

для j++;
    movl    __gthrw___pthread_key_create(unsigned int*, void (*)(void*)), %eax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je      .L2
    movl    $m, %edi
    call    __gthrw_pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t*)
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jne     .L8
    movl    $m, %edi
    addl    $1, j(%rip)
    call    __gthrw_pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t*)
```

не совсем понятно что кроется за pthread-овскими функциями...

Comment: Да даже если они так и реализованы (хотя какое ещё "если" -- иначе мьютексы были б ненадёжны -- они **точно** реализованы на атомарных операциях), вместо одной атомарной операции во втором случае нужно выполнять несколько. Нет?

Comment: Это правда, так просто быстрее. С другой стороны, код `multithreaded_func() { m.lock(); i++; j--; m.unlock(); }` вы уже не сможете переписать на atomic-переменные.

Comment: @D-side, а почему больше?

Comment: @VladD, а можно подробнее почему не сможем?

Comment: @xperious просто потому что больше действий. Хотя бы на тела функций посмотрите, в первом случае действие одно, во втором три.

Comment: @D-side, честно, не понимаю откуда три

Comment: Строчки/инструкции в теле функции посчитайте :)

Comment: @D-side, i там неатомарная

Comment: А я и не говорил, что три *атомарных* операции. Время-то занимают любые.

Comment: @D-side, три инструкции для инкремента это ничто по сравнению с инструкцией lock

Comment: Перечитайте примечание в скобках в первом комментарии.

Comment: @xperious: Потому что если мы перепишем это на atomic-переменные, то атомарным будет каждое из присваиваний по отдельности, но не оба вместе. Это значит, что другой поток сможет увидеть первую переменную изменённой, а вторую нет.

Comment: С удовольствием взял попкорн (комментарии уже доставляют) ;)